# Is there a way to calculate the $Q$-factor?

Tags: acoustics, resonance

I’d like to calculate the [$Q$-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) for an acoustically resonating object. I’d like to keep the tests to a minimal, none if possible. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information, for example what kind of resonating object? A tuning fork? A tube with a standing sound wave inside? What kind of set-up do you visualize

Comment: @Triatticus I’m trying to compare the resonance strength of a tube and a box when sound waves are affecting them

Answer (score 1):

Measure the decay time. The number of oscillations for the amplitude to decay to $1/e =37$ % gives you the Q-factor.